# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError, No virtual method log(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, intercom

I have add Itercom Chat for Customer support or Contact Us. But When I add Intercom sdk dependency
(**implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:9.**+') and App run then crash my App. i get error like below

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method log(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable; V in class Lokhttp3/internal/platform/Platform;

or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform' appears in /data/app/com.exampla.app-Opatc6X6ZSZqGt8Wv1Uwty==/base.apk!classes3.dex)

Comment: Facing the same issue

Answer (score 27):

You have to use the same version of the okHttp library.
in my case it was

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
```

Which was throwing this exception which is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method log(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable; V in class Lokhttp3/internal/platform/Platform;
```

So fix will be in your build.gradle file you have to use same versions:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.2'
```

It will fix your issue. This is too late to share an answer but might help others also.